# Cocoon + acts_as_taggable_on not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to use Cocoon and acts_as_taggable_on together.

I have an Answer which belongs to a Question. The Answer is the tagged one and I use Cocoon to deal with those.

### Answer Model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

### Question Model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The Answers tag just fine on Answer creation but when I try to update them, it fails (I'm not quite sure where). This is all running through ActiveAdmin as well and I'm thinking about just writing custom controller actions but that seems like overkill when it should just work.

### Questions Form (erb)

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @question] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs "Question" do %>
      <%= f.input :text %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="answers">
        <%= f.semantic_fields_for :answers do |a| %>
            <%= render "answer_fields", :f => a %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add answer', f, :answers %>
    </div>
    <%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

### Answers Cocoon Partial

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :text %>
        <%= f.label :tag_list %>
        <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_answers_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association "remove answer", f %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: when editing a question, can you add and remove answers? Or when editing a question, and editing the tags for an answer, those don't save?